# Symfony2 add extern class

Tags: php, symfony

I have some classes that I want to add to the project in Symfony but it's a bit diffucult. I tried in many ways but still can't use a class.

My classes are stored in Model folder : `src/project/MyBundle/Model/`

I added the name space in my class `namespace Project\MyBundle\Model;`

And in the controller the use `use Project\MyBundle\Model\Vendor;`

and the call `$vendor = new \Vendor($cin);`.

But this doesn't work. I get this error

```
Attempted to load class "Vendor" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Some help pls

Comment: _Attempted to load class "Vendor" from the global namespace._ That's it. You mean `$vendor = new Vendor($cin);`

Comment: Yeah either dump the `use` and use `new \Project\MyBundle\Model\Vendor($cin)` or keep it as it is and use `new Vendor($cin)`.

Comment: I tried without the back slash it works now

Answer (score 0):

Define it as service:

```
my_service:
    class: Project\MyBundle\Model\MyClass
```

In controller you can use it like this:

```
$this->container->get('my_service');
```